# nginx, fpm - Bad Gateway error on php

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

i'm stuck here with a Bad Gateway issues and PHP

I use Nginx 1.6 in combination with FPM on Debian Wheezy. Its a clean and new installation. But everytime if i run a php file it will result in a Bad Gateway error.

So i read nearly all that i found to that issue but nothing helped.

From the setup i use multiple vhosts (by Ipsconfig Management). FPM is running on Unix Sockets as every vhost conf.

Example:

```
listen = /var/lib/php5-fpm/web4.sock
listen.owner = web4
listen.group = client1
listen.mode = 0660

user = web4
group = client1

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_requests = 0

chdir = /
```

My pool ww conf looks like http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4BU4sTEs

My FPM config http://pastebin.com/gDcgV0aZ

From that side all sockets are in the specific folder, but causes only Bad Gateway messages. The Logfile is empty nothing special also in debug mode.

Disturbing is, if i change in the vhost of nginx

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock;
```

to

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

It is working! But this is not how it should be, normaly he should take 
*fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock;* (or web4.. web3). from the sub folder.

This produce no error message in the log but is yust not working.

Answer (score 0):

I gave finally Up, it is likely that it was due a defunction in the nginx packets. This morning i made a new installation of debian and the issue was gone.